# How do I pass touch events through to parentViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have a UIViewContoller with a few container(child) UIiewsController. The main UIViewController (mvc) contains:

- 1.) A UICollectionView that occupies the entire view of mvc (it is above mvc.view but below all other controls).
- 2.) A UIViewController that displays search options (s1vc)
- 3.) another similar to #2 (s2vc)
- 4.) another similar to #2 (s3vc)

[image]

I have added gesture recognizers to mvc so that a user can hide/show each of the child view controllers by swiping them off of the screen.

The problem is that when a user swipes any of the svcs off of the screen, they cannot scroll the mvc's collectionView.

Here is how I am hiding/showing the svcs:

```
-(void)swipeLeftGestureHandler:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
    SMLOG(@"Swiped Left");
    if([SMUser activeUser] == nil) return;
    if([self gestureHorizontalScreenSide:gestureRecognizer] == kHorizontalScreenSideLeft){
        [self hideFacets];
    }
    else{
        [self showAccordion];
    }
}
-(void)swipeRightGestureHandler:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
    SMLOG(@"Swiped Right");
    if([SMUser activeUser] == nil) return;
    if([self gestureHorizontalScreenSide:gestureRecognizer] == kHorizontalScreenSideLeft){
        [self showFacets];
    }
    else{
        [self hideAccordion];
    }
}

-(void)hideFacets{
    if(self.facetVisible == NO) return;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect newFrame = self.facetViewController.view.frame;
                         newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(newFrame.origin.x - newFrame.size.width, newFrame.origin.y);
                         self.facetViewController.view.frame = newFrame;
                         self.facetVisible = NO;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         self.facetViewController.view.hidden = YES;
                         self.facetViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                     }];
}

-(void)showFacets{
    if([SMUser activeUser] == nil) return;
    if(self.facetVisible == YES) return;

    self.facetViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         self.facetViewController.view.hidden = NO;
                         CGRect newFrame = self.facetViewController.view.frame;
                         newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(newFrame.origin.x + newFrame.size.width, newFrame.origin.y);
                         self.facetViewController.view.frame = newFrame;
                         self.facetVisible = YES;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){         
                     }];
}
```

As you can see I'm toggling the svc.view.hidden property and then I also tried toggling th svc.userInteractionEnabled.property but no luck. Still cannot swipe the collection view by swiping where the facets view controller was/is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to add another outlet (using IB) for the container view in the parentViewController (I called it facetContainerView in this code) and then set it's userInteractionEnabled property.

```
-(void)hideFacets{
    if(self.facetVisible == NO) return;
    self.facetVisible = NO;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect newFrame = self.facetViewController.view.frame;
                         newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(newFrame.origin.x - newFrame.size.width, newFrame.origin.y);
                         self.facetViewController.view.frame = newFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         self.facetViewController.view.hidden = YES;
                         self.facetContainerView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                     }];
}

-(void)showFacets{
    if(self.facetVisible == YES) return;
    self.facetVisible = YES;
    self.facetContainerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         self.facetViewController.view.hidden = NO;
                         CGRect newFrame = self.facetViewController.view.frame;
                         newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(newFrame.origin.x + newFrame.size.width, newFrame.origin.y);
                         self.facetViewController.view.frame = newFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){         
                     }];
}
```

I was curious as to how this new view outlet was different from self.facetViewController.view, so I inserted this code to compare addresses (they are different indeed). I'm not sure about the heirarchy, but it seems that there is an extra view layer that I was not aware of.

```
NSLog(@"self.facetViewController.view: %p", self.facetViewController.view);
NSLog(@"self.facetContainerView: %p", self.facetContainerView);
```

Hopefully this will help someone at some point.